# linking timers to variables

Tags: c#, timer

I am making a food ordering desktop application , so i want to calculate time between ordering food and delivering food so i added timers to the app and made a start and end buttons , on starting i start a time and put it interval value ,make a variable counter, count and save its value on end button to database , what i want to made is to start a new timer dynamically on new orders and when ending an order stop its timer

i tried inserting 3 timers and made variables c1,c2,c3 and made a loop to start timers on every order if interval!=null , but i didn't know how to stop a specific timer on ending the order

code :

```
    int c1=0;
    int c2=0;
    int c3=0;
    private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Interval == null)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
        }
        else if (timer2.Interval == null)
        {
            timer2.Start();
            timer2.Interval = 1000;
        }
        else if (timer3.Interval == null)
        {
            timer3.Start();
            timer3.Interval = 1000;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are unaware of `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

Comment: i tried stop watch but i didn't know how to link it with vairables on stopping

Comment: And we don't know what you have tried.... Don't you think you should post your code and ask where you got stuck?

Comment: done posting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you have not shown us any code, let me assume that you at least have a class to encapsulate order.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber{get;set;}

    ///other properties
}
```

Now if you add following two properties and a method, your problem is resolved.

```
    public class Order
{
    public int OrderNumber{get;set;}

    //other properties

    public DateTime OrderPlacedOn{get;set;}
    public DateTime OrderCompletedOn{get;set;}

    public TimeSpan TimeToComplete()
    {
        if(OrderCompletedOn==DateTime.MinValue)//order not completed yet
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

        return OrderCompletedOn - OrderPlacedOn;
    }
}
```

This saves you from keeping countless timers. You can set values of start and complete on clicking of your buttons.

Comment: thanks, but i want user to see a stopwatch or timer value on screen to see order time

Comment: Don't know much how you are building up your UI. But you can have a component (control) which displays running time and stop it when the button is clicked. That way you have `Timer` encapsulated inside the control and you don't have to deal with 10-20 of them. Have methods like `StartTimer` and `StopTimer` in control . On placing order you can create a control and show in UI and call `StartTimer`. Update display every second.